# Android Studio rendering problems, using it for the first time

Tags: java, android

I have started learning android.

I am using Android Studio 1.5 and Java jdk 1.8.0_65.
I am sure that the environment variables path are properly set.

So what I try to do is, start android studio -> create new project -> select phone and tablet with minumum sdk API 8 -> add a blank activity -> finish

At first there are no problems, but when I try to change the theme to material light, this is the error I get,

[image]

I have tried clearing the cache and restarting, but it doesn't work

The app dependencies look like this
[image]

In the dropdown menu of Android version to use when rendering layouts in the IDE, I get only one option

[image]

The build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jeet.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

The AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jeet.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And if it helps, these are the packages installed in the SDK manager,

[image]

What should I do to solve these issues? I could use another theme, but I would like to understand the reason for these problems and solve them.

Comment: Check out which theme layout designer uses to render your xml. You can see it to the left of the dropdown menu you mentioned (see https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhl9gg3rwoba2vq/Screenshot%202015-11-22%2021.28.33.png?dl=0) It should be AppTheme.

Comment: @RobertoArtilesAstelarra, I guess you are talking about the fourth button in your screenshot, I have set it to Theme.Material.Light and that's when I am getting the error in my first screenshot.

Comment: @RobertoArtilesAstelarra, and when I set it to AppTheme, I get an error stating android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar could not be found

Comment: Also make sure that in styles.xml AppTheme extends Theme.AppCompat.Light.

Comment: By the way, as a side note: changing theme in Layout Designer doesn't affect the app's actual theme. It just affects how layout is rendered in a preview mode.

Comment: I tried creating the project again, this time using empty activity instead of blank activity, and now there are no problems at all. Still didn't understand what was the issue though, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity will be extending "AppCompatActivity" which requires that an appcompat theme need to be used. You can change it to "Activity" and try other themes.

Comment: I do the changes in MainActivity.java, correct? If I change it to "Activity", other errors come up in MainActivity.java, one of it says, `cannot resolve method setSupportActionBar(Android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)`

Comment: Yes. In MainActivity. Codes for handling Toolbar and Floating Action Bar in MainActivity needs that activity to extend AppCompatActivity. So to run the app you need to remove the lines below setContentView method in onCreate. Also remove support design library components used in activity_main layout file. Then the app should run, though without toolbar and FAB

Comment: BTW You can create a toolbar even without extending AppCompatActivity, though not as straight forward as using it. Refer https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/how-to-add-toolbar-to-an-activity-which-doesn-t-extend-appcompatactivity-a07c026717b3#.8nxl6qqgp

Comment: I tried creating the project again, this time using empty activity instead of blank activity, and now there are no problems at all. Still didn't understand what was the issue though, but thanks anyways.

Comment: On creating new project using empty activity you would have noted that there was no tool bar and floating action bar components created. These components caused crash for you earlier after you changed MainActivity to extend "Activity". These design support library components depend on AppCompat library. Since these are not present when created app using empty activity, just changing the theme to material light and the parent of MainActivity to "Activity" made your code run.

Comment: got it, thanks... and about that drop down menu which I mentioned in my question, do I have to install previous android APIs from the SDK manager to get more options in the drop down menu?

Comment: the problem is still there, I made my activity extend "Activity" and removed the lines below setContentView as you told, but I still get rendering problem about CoordinatorLayout, any idea about it?

Comment: Coordinatorlayout is also an android design support library component. It would be better that you  change the layout of MainActivity to content_main as we are not using additional components in activity_main layout.  Regarding API levels displayed in dropdown menu you need to install previous android APIs as you said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96027/discussion-between-human123-and-vicky96).